# Bulk sharpen a directory of images with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

How can I point imagemagick to a directory of images and use the adaptive sharpen tool to increase the sharpness of all the files in the folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really belongs on SuperUser i think as it relates more to general purpose scripting as opposed to programming... However, if youre *nix you could do the following with a bash script:

```
for f in /path/to/images/*; \
do echo "Sharpening $f file.." \
&& OUTPUT_FILE="sharpened.`basename $f`" \
&& echo "Output to $OUTPUT_FILE" \
&& convert $f OPTIONS $OUTPUT_FILE; \
done
```

`OPTIONS` would be all your options for the `convert` utility. This also assumes all `/path/to/images` ONLY contains image files convert can use and not directories or other types of files. You could modify it to be more smart if you wanted but youre on your own for that :-) Additionally, this will put the output files in whatever directory youre in, but you could easily supply a full path as the part of the `$OUTPUT_FILE` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been asked and answered on the ImageMagick forum

[How to "Smart Sharpen," adaptive-sharpen not working](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10266)

> I'd like to be able to batch sharpen
>   my photos, then just work on the ones that need more attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.jpg|xargs -n 1 -P #cpus -t command_to_sharpen
```

There's also a good wrapper for the protocol described here: http://gimpguru.org/Tutorials/SmartSharpening2/ at http://astoryworthtelling.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/smart-sharpening-in-imagemagick/